# Combine: how to early exit with error from a guard precondition

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want to create a method `authenticate` which, using Combine, allows the user to login with my API.

I am trying to add now a precondition, so that if the provided username is empty, my method does not touch the network. I want to make an early exist at this point, providing an error back to the Subscriber.

Please find below an snippet of my code. How could I return an error from the early exist in line 4?

```
func authenticate(username: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<User, Error> {

        guard !username.isEmpty else {
            // How to return an error to the subscribers from here?????
            return
        }

        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        ]

        var request = URLRequest(endpoint: Endpoint.login)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: AuthenticationResult.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .map { $0.user }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: You could emit an Empty or a Fail, it’s really up you how you want to treat the pipeline. Since data task publisher will only publish once in any case, I think Fail would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Fail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail), which is a type of `Publisher`:

```swift
return Fail(error: MyError.missingUsername).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```